# fetch csv file and read

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, fs

My simple script easily reads data from local csv files:

```
const csv = require('csv-parse');
const fs = require('fs');
const file = './files/projects.csv';

const run = () => {
  fs.createReadStream(file)
    .pipe(
      csv({
        trim: true,
        columns: true,
        delimiter: ',',
        skip_empty_lines: true
      })
    )
    .on('data', row => {
        console.log('***', row)
    })
};

run();
```

how I can read in the same way data from csv files which are not stored locally and have url address like "https://example.com/files/project.csv"?

Thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pipe http request responses in a similar way to file streams. This code fetches a file from `https://example.com/example.csv`. (I think)

```
var http = require("http"); //HTTP module
var csv = require('csv-parse'); //CSV module

var url = "https://example.com/example.csv";
http.request(url, response => { //Make request to URL
  response.pipe(
    //YOUR CODE
    csv({
      trim: true,
      columns: true,
      delimiter: ',',
      skip_empty_lines: true
    })
  ).on('data', row => {
    console.log('***', row)
  });
}).end();
```